# How to return a different type based on a enum argument

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, std-variant, stdany

I have two functions which require the following:

Function 1: Requires the address of a variable to set the value. ( It knows about the correct type)

Function 2: Is a overloaded function which requires the value of a type.

I need a way to return a different types based on a enum (Which specifies type to use).

I tried to use std::get as you can use a number to specify the type.
However it requires SelectedType to be a constant expression which it is not.

```
std::variant<uint8_t,int8_t,uint16_t,int16_t,double,float> Var;
std::get<SelectedTypeEnum>(Var)
```

The point is to use *one* variable to avoid code repetition.

Consider the following code:

```
enum Type{
Type_uint8_t,
Type_int8_t,
Type_uint16_t,
Type_int16_t,
Type_std::string
} TypeList;

GetTypeToUse(Type&){ /* Get/Set the type to use */ }

void SetValueBasedOnEnum(Type TypeToUse,void* ptr) {/* Function 1: Sets the value of the type */}

// This is a  Overloaded Function which supports all types in the enum. 
//"T" represents the type.
void DoStuffWithDifferentTypes(T ValueOfType) { /*Function 2:*/ }
```

Comment: How about `template <Type type> auto GetTypeToUse()`? Can `Type` be a compile time constant?

Comment: Oh that part is already provided by a library I'm using I added it for context. I need to figure out how write **Function 2**. With Function 1 only has a one type so you can just do  &std::any_cast<T&>

Comment: C++ is a strongly typed language. Every function has a fix return type. What you intend to do, though, requires your function to have more than one return type, depending on function parameter value, contradicting the strongly typed-ness, so no, you won't be able to get there, at least not the way you intend...

Answer (score 5):

You cannot return a different type based on the value of an enumeration passed to the function.  A functions signature is set at compile time so anything that would change it has to be a compile time construct.

If you have to return different types that you can only know at run time then you can use a `std::variant` or `std::any` for that.  `std::variant` is basically a tagged union so you have to specify which types it can hold.  If you have a bounded set of types, this the the preferred data structure.  If you have an unbounded set of types, then you can use `std::any`.  It uses type erasure and dynamic memory allocation so it is a lot more expensive to use than a `std::variant` but that is the cost you have to pay to get unlimited flexibility.

Another option, if it makes sense for you use case, is to have all the types inherit from a common base type.  Then you can return a pointer to base from the function but work with the object polymorphicly.